# Are there any guidelines about making SQL queries easier to comprehend?

Tags: sql, coding-standards

As I'm spending more time working with SQL, I'm starting to feel like this language promotes logic obfuscation. Here are some examples:

An `INNER JOIN` in a query can act as an implicit filter that reduces the result set into a subset. However, to understand what is being filtered, you needs to have knowledge of the tables involved, which is information not present in the query syntax.
A query like

```
SELECT *
FROM quotations
INNER JOIN shipments USING(quotationid)
```

...can either give you quotations that have been shipped if `shipments` contains only shipment records that actually happened, or it could give you an undefined subset of quotations if `shipments` contains shipment entries that go through multiple stages, and a line in `shipment` can mean anything from 'shipment in preparation' to 'shipment partially sent' to 'shipment reached destination'. Needless to say, unless you know this information, you can't look at the above query and figure out what it means.

Then we can look at something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM quotations
LEFT OUTER JOIN shipments USING(shipmentid)
WHERE shipment_date IS NULL
```

Clearly this query returns a set of quotations that have existing shipment records, but the fact that you can obtain this by filtering for `shipment_date IS NULL` is insane from a logic perspective.
You can say that this is a contrived example and that I should just pick a better column, but there isn't always a very logical, self documenting alternative to choose from, so bear with me on this.

Then there's the fact that naming result sets is sometimes a compromise between properly describing the result set data, and communicating its intended meaning. Let's say that you want to use a subquery on `shipments` that returns some information about foreign shipments from last year. All you really need from this subquery is the answer to whether a shipment is foreign or not, but you also need to return a quotation id to JOIN it with the `quotations` table, and you also need to return the shipment date to filter by last year so you might as well do it from this sub query, and maybe you actually care about some other extra details like the specific country. So what do you call this collection of quotation_id, is_foreign, shipment_date, and country? Either something fairly generic which won't communicate its indented purpose but will encompass all 4 data points properly, or something very descriptive but long and cumbersome. None of these is an appealing option.

I can rant some more, and I know these aren't perfect examples, but I hope you get my point. It seems to me that declarative languages pose some unique challenges for code clarity that requires unique tools and guidelines to handle, and I wonder if there's some good literature on this?

Comment: The character and complexity of the SQL is in direct proportion to the robustness of your table design (and the implicit logic that it carries).  Bad table design means bad SQL.

Comment: @RobertHarvey You know what, I think your comment is probably the real answer to my question. A procedural language is a lot more self-contained in terms of where its logic lies, because it uses a vocabulary of actions to describe actions, so it's much closer to being self-documenting than SQL which has to contend with a division between data organization and data traversal, and it's not designed to be able to describe both. Essentially my complaints boils down to the fact that you can't document database structure using query syntax, you can only make sure the structure is not complicated.

Comment: A procedural language wouldn't be as simple and self-contained if it actually did what SQL does. Am I right in understanding that what your complaint is, is that the *relationships* between tables (which express, for example, what joins are permissible in principle) are not documented in the query?

Comment: Occasionally, given a particular part of the SQL and the knwoledge of the RDBMS we're using, we add a comment (/* */) into the SQL statements themselves. We have those stored in a database table as well.

Comment: You would face all the exact same problems in a procedural language if you were approaching a complex codebase without understanding the domain or the software requirements behind it.   Without that, you'd have absolutely no point of reference with which to understand why it works in such a way or whether the code is right or not.    The bottom line for any complex technology is that you always need an understanding of the context which goes with it in order to be able to productively work with that technology - whether it's a tool, language, framework, etc.

Comment: This would be an excellent question if the actual question weren't a literature request, which unfortunately is explicitly out of scope for this board.

Comment: @BenCottrell I don’t entirely agree. Large unfamiliar code bases can indeed be hard to get into, but a procedural language can do a very good job of modeling the problem domain in such a way that you can actually learn about the problem domain from reading the code. SQL is much more linguistically focused and it’s way harder to express the inner logic of the problem domain with it.

Comment: @kilianfoth how do you recommend I change it? It is my understanding that questions that promote discussion aren’t welcomed in SE websites and I was trying to narrow it down into something answerable since my question isn’t about any specific class of SQL queries, but on the general nature of SQL itself as a language.

Comment: SQL is poorly designed & poorly relational. Compare 
 [Re relational querying.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24425914/3404097) 
&  [Null in Relational Algebra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55663848/null-in-relational-algebra) 
 (especially the latter's PS summary) with [Is there any rule of thumb to construct SQL query from a human-readable description?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33952141/3404097). Sadly the relational model is poorly taught & understood. SQL moreso. [Re how relational algebra & predicate \[sic\] calculus go together.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32841232/3404097)

Comment: How is it you expect to program without knowing what is represented by the variables? (Rhetorical.)

Comment: @philipxy The complaint was not about having to know what is represented by the variables, it's about being able to infer it from self-documenting code, which seems harder to achieve using SQL.

Comment: @philipxy, I agree with you that teaching is poor, and real-world implementations are not properly described by relational theory (or set theory, since implementations have so-called bag/multiset semantics, rather than set semantics). I've been thinking a lot lately about the problem, and in my view a main omission in teaching material, is that it does not provide a foundational understanding of array operations on lists of values. It would be like teaching conventional algebra, without starting with basic arithmetic and manipulation of numbers. Does that ring true to you?

Comment: @Primordial_Hamster, I'm still struggling to understand what exactly it is that you would like to infer from SQL code, but cannot? In particularly interested to understand whether you're hitting on things that experienced users like myself recognise as deficient (such as the non-obvious and seemingly absurd order of evaluation), whether you've just misunderstood it in its own terms (and we can help), or whether experienced users have just learned to have a blind spot or to compensate for its failings.

Comment: @Steve I don't know why you say arrays & lists matter. To explain SQL bag/table arithmetic? What matters is, a relation expression corresponds to a statement parameterized by attribute names & the former's value is the latter's satisfying tuples. Yes bags & null<>null are big mistakes nothing to do with that, alas needed to use SQL. Yes bag & set arithmetic are used, although "theory" is ubiquitous hyperbole. See my links. I don't seek to discuss, I might answer, I originally commented to link to important fundamentals missing in the question's conception of relational reasoning.

Comment: @Steve & Primordial_Hamster You might be interested in [Hugh Darwen's relational model & SQL free online introductory books](https://bookboon.com/en/author/0908031c-ce02-9b86-11e6-6dd7d2c299d1). (Not enough showing of the parallel between relation expressions & statement templates though.)

Comment: @philipxy, I say they matter because I conceive of SQL as performing array operations on tables, and part of the way in which I write queries in practice involves mentally manipulating such tables. I only mention "bags" to emphasise that real SQL implementations are not explicable by either relational theory or plain set theory. I'm convinced that the way in which relational theory is taught formally (at least so far as the intended audience are computer programmers and/or SQL users) suffers from tremendous defects in these respects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So many complaints to answer!

The first thing I'd point out is that SQL does not make naming things easier, or prescribe a system of naming. This is a perennial problem in all software design.

Secondly, it is possible to design relational databases in ways which are obtuse. Many people nowadays who design databases have no practical experience in business administration - and a designer who specifies a system for administering logistics, for example, may have no specific knowledge of administration in areas like logistics, no experience whatsoever with the standard design patterns and conceptual systems in that area which have withstood a test of time and are found to be convincing and convenient to staff who work in those areas. Again though, this is a perennial problem in all software design which is not confined to databases.

Thirdly, in SQL, you do need to understand the tables themselves, the meaning of the columns, the ways in which applications manipulate the data, and the rules that govern legitimate operations or states from illegitimate ones. This is not an oversight or a language deficiency. You do have to invest significant time to build a mental model of databases, in order to work effectively with them. If there is inadequate documentation available to you, or inadequate informal knowledge in a team, about how the database works, then that is the same problem as with any undocumented software system given to an inexperienced developer.

Fourthly, in SQL, you have to properly understand what the *operators* do. Virtually everyone has a basic mathematical education in which they learn addition, multiplication, and so on. But addition in that context operates on individual values - such as `2+2`, where the '2's are single values.

In SQL, the operators (such as `join`) transform *tables* of values according to fixed rules, and most people (even programmers) have no prior exposure to such techniques before they come to use SQL, let alone any education in them (and I would note, in passing, that I broadly consider educational materials to be uncompelling).

Hopefully this provides some food for thought, and perhaps a basis for further clarification, on the issues you've raised.

Comment: Having taken some time to consider everything, I've come to the conclusion that whoever designed the database I inherited did a terrible job. With procedural language you have a lot of expressive freedom to write the logic in a way that also communicates the design itself, and these tricks aren't available in a declarative language such as SQL, but I wouldn't be feeling the need for these tricks if the database was designed in a way that makes sense to begin with.

Answer (score 6):

Fundamentally, SQL is SQL. 
It's not Basic, or C, or HTML.  It's SQL.  Quite often, it's some DBMS-specific *variant* of the [ANSI] SQL standard to boot. 
I'm sorry to say you just have to get *used* to it.

As you quite rightly say:

> ... you needs to have knowledge of the tables ...

Forgive some straight-talking here, but ...   Hell, yes!

I would state things even more bluntly:

> You need to know what you're working with.

Relational Databases are inherently *structured* resources.  They are structured in particular ways for any number of Reasons and, without a good grasp of those Reasons, you're largely blundering around, blind.

This "strangeness of expression" is one of the "reasons" I've heard given for the use of Object-Relational Mapping (ORM) tools, which "abstract" the Developer *away* from that strange, oddly-syntaxed SQL "thing" - i.e. the Database - and allows them to stay "comfortable" in their largely *procedural* mindset.

Such Developers are more likely to complain that "the database is slow" (sigh; rolls eyes) or come looking for help with tuning queries that perform appallingly badly or, worse still, individual queries that are as good as they get, and yet their Application is running like a slug (Oh; the *Joys* of the "1+n Query" model).

I find that those Developers who take the time and trouble to understand *something* about the Database they're working with produce *far better* results because they work *with* their DBMS.

Comment: I would argue that the problem is not a procedural mindset. A procedural approach in which data structures are passed between methods to be manipulated, is actually the *best* way to understand and reason about SQL - albeit with the loss of loops and row-at-a-time idioms that most procedural programmers actually know. It is a specific object-oriented mindset which is most incompatible.

Answer (score 2):

> I’m starting to feel like this language promotes logic obfuscation.

A programming language is only a mean for the programmer to express what he/she wants the system to do.

It goes for SQL like for English language: if a sentence cannot be understood, is ambiguous or incomplete, it’s probably more caused by the writer’s skills than the English grammar, isn’t it ?

> You need to have knowledge of the tables involved

Indeed, this is completely true. Again, if comparing with the English language, you must have knowledge of your topic in order to write relevant statements or essays.

So I propose you to stop ranting, and exercise yourself to make your queries more expressive. It’s by doing it and trying that you’ll get comfortable at it. Here some tips:

- [article](https://it.badykov.com/blog/2018/09/23/sql-queries/) with some very basic tips
- [nice article](https://365datascience.com/sql-best-practices/) about SQL coding style
- [SO advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/394876) on inner join syntax
- don’t forget that you can alias table names to help you making statements clearer by revealing the intent on the use of the secundary tables.

*By the way, if you are interested primarily in quotation information, you should not need to join with shipment in the first place. And from a business perspective, one is generally interested to know which quotation where followed by an order, or what order was shipped. But the relation between a quote and a shipment does make less sense, especially if several shipments can be made for the same quote. So maybe there is room for improvement in the data model as well. But this is too broad for here.*

Answer (score -1):

SQL has always been problematic.

Codd's original relation theory work used mathematical type symbols to express filters and joins. Alas the IBM management of the time wanted an end user query system and came up with SQL as the query language to access relational databases.

Competing products, notably RAMIS, had a much cleaner and logical syntax but without the might of IBM (as was) they never really got market share.

Having had to write a parser to analize SQL I can tell you as a language is a mess! Some 2500 lines for the Antlr g4 grammer definition for MySQL.

But the underlying relational model is one of the best ways to reflect real world data -- especially in a business/administration context. So you are pretty much stuck with SQL for the foreseeable future.